# Visual Studio vs Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Quisiera saber el cual es la diferencia entre estos 2 IDE's, soy programador de videojuegos pero quiero saber cual es la diferencia entre estos dos ya que los nombre son similares
Saludos

Comment: Eso esta en el faq de visual studio code https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_what-is-the-difference-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio-ide

Comment: Vale la pena apuntar que vsCode no es un IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabes hay una gran diferencia entre ambos pero intentaré darme a entender de forma fácil.

- Visual Studio = entorno de desarrollo de lenguajes de programación F#, c#, c++, VB.
- Visual Studio Code = editor de textos, usado como entorno de desarrollo web y consola.